# How to use comparator twice in a row?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the Comparator to sort a list by time and points, time being more important and if the objects have the same time then comparing the points.

Here is what I have tried, but it does not turn out exactly the way I would like.

Am I comparing it incorrectly?

```
Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {
            public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
                int endShiftInt = (int) p1.getEndShift()/1000;
                int endShiftInt2 = (int) p2.getEndShift()/1000;

                if(endShiftInt == endShiftInt2) {
                    Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {
                        public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
                            return Integer.valueOf(p1.getPoints()).compareTo(p2.getPoints());
                        }
                    });
                }
                return Integer.valueOf(endShiftInt).compareTo(endShiftInt2);
            }
        });
```

I have also tried this:

```
Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {
            public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(p1.getPoints()).compareTo(p2.getPoints());
            }
        });

        //sortUsers in order of last Time They Guarded, those with a higher number is more recent, then lower numbers first
        Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {
            public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
                int endShiftInt = (int) p1.getEndShift()/1000;
                int endShiftInt2 = (int) p2.getEndShift()/1000;

                return Integer.valueOf(endShiftInt).compareTo(endShiftInt2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Think about what that inner comparator is going to do.  As soon as you find _a single match_ between the endShiftInts then it will sort _the entire list_ based on the points...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler than that. Use something like:

```
    Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {

        public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
            int endShiftInt = (int) p1.getEndShift() / 1000;
            int endShiftInt2 = (int) p2.getEndShift() / 1000;

            if (endShiftInt == endShiftInt2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(p1.getPoints()).compareTo(p2.getPoints());
            }
            return Integer.valueOf(endShiftInt).compareTo(endShiftInt2);
        }
    }
    );
```

Essentially - if the first attribute is the same then it is the difference between the second attribute that should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to call sort two times with two different comparator. Replace your code with the following.

```
Collections.sort(onlyGuardsStatArray, new Comparator<DatabaseGuard>() {
    public int compare(DatabaseGuard p1, DatabaseGuard p2) {
       int endShiftInt = (int) p1.getEndShift()/1000;
       int endShiftInt2 = (int) p2.getEndShift()/1000;

       if (endShiftInt == endShiftInt2) {
           return Integer.valueOf(p1.getPoints()).compareTo(p2.getPoints());
       }
       return endShiftInt - endShiftInt2;  // I make a little Optimization here
   }
});
```